# ¿Es correcto editar una pregunta cerrada de otro usuario para mejorarla?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, ediciones

Mi consulta apunta a la [siguiente pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79642/construyendo-gr%C3%A1ficos-en-ggplot2), la misma claramente no alcanza los requerimientos mínimos de una buena pregunta. Sin duda yo me apuré a contestarla (mea culpa) porque me quedaba más que claro cuál era el problema y al usuario evidentemente la respuesta le sirvió. **¿Que es lo correcto en estos casos?** a ver:

1. Editar la pregunta original agregando el ejemplo mínimo y reproducible más toda la información necesaria
2. Armar una nueva pregunta y autoresponderla

Mis disculpas si esto ya se trató, pero no encontré ningún respuesta por esto en Meta.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que una pregunta cerrada que se edite, entra en la cola de reapertura.

Comment: Si, por supuesto @lois6b.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sí es correcto editar una pregunta para mejorarla.
Siempre que se respete la intención original del autor así como el significado original de su pregunta.

Puedes leer en
[Centro de Ayuda > Privilegios > editar preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)
:

> ### Cuándo debería editar publicaciones?
>
> Siempre que veas que puedes mejorar una publicación y te apetezca.
> ¡Fomentamos la edición!
>
> Algunas razones comunes para editar son:
>
> - para corregir errores gramaticales o de ortografía
> - para clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla
> - para corregir errores mínimos o añadir apéndices / actualizaciones a medida que la publicación envejece
> - para añadir recursos o enlaces relacionados
>
> **No os animamos a hacer ediciones minúsculas o triviales**: intenta
> mejorar la publicación considerablemente cuando la edites, corrigiendo
> todos los problemas que encuentres.

La pregunta que enlazas sin duda necesita ser mejorada para ser aceptable. Siéntete libre de editarla para alcanzar los estándares del sitio. Pero ten en cuenta que si el autor original se mostrase en desacuerdo con tu edición debes respetar su criterio en general.

Respecto a las dos opciones que planteas, editar o pregunta nueva. Ambas son aceptables. Si haces una nueva no será cerrada por duplicada porque la original ya está cerrada. Haz lo que prefieras.

La pregunta original se hizo ya hace casi dos semanas. Si fuese una hecha hace poco entonces no vería como una buena opción el hacer una pregunta nueva; hay que darle opción al autor original de editar su preguta. En este caso la edición sigue siendo buena opción.

Comment: Gracias @Jose Antonio Dura Olmos, ¿el "Para añadir recursos o enlaces relacionados" podría incluir agregar un ejemplo mínimo y verificable que el usuario obvio incorporar?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Puedes añadir un ejemplo mínimo y verificable que se corresponda con la intención original de la pregunta.